# Data source in Jasper reports

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I am using *Jasper Reports Server* opensource 4.5 version.

While uploading a report, everytime, I have to link the new report to a data source.

I have created a data source and my all reports run on same data source.

Is there any way to set the data source as default so that all the new reports automatically links to the data source?

Answer (score 0):

How do you upload your reports to jasperserver? If you use the plugin in iReport, it's very simple to link the datasource because you can just choose the datasource from the repository.

Comment: This can be done in jasper server also. We can add datasources in repository and select from there while uploading the reports. I want a method for setting a default datasource for the reports. Don't want to select from repository while uploading.